# Adding New Solr Datacenter

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to add new solr datacenter. After nodes are up then rebuild datacenter, i see that streaming processes are done but secondary index building processes is still going. In my opinion, the secondary index processes take 10 days.

At this point

1) Do i restart nodes after bootstrap process is done while secondary index building process is still going?

2) If i restart node while solr reindexing is going, after restart, the reindexing process continue where the process left or reindex all data from beginning?

Comment: Its a bit worrying your indexes are expected to take 10 days to build. Can you elaborate on what hardware you have in the original question please?

Comment: @markc actually i am very stuck because of solr reindexing. I have been dealing for two months. Still could not find decent solution. I have 150GB data and 1TB solr index data on a node. I have 32 core hyper thread machine, 1ssd for commitlog, 1 raid 10 hdd disk, 64 GB ram. Solr dc has 3 nodes. For test purpose, i replaced raid 10 hdd solr disk with 1 raid 10 ssd. But the result are same, the nodes have same indexing throughput.

Comment: Theres a lot of factors at play here, firstly can you add these specs to your original question. In addition to this it would also be useful to see: cql table schema, `solrconfig.xml`, `solrschema.xml` and `dse.yaml`. Not sure where you could add those, perhaps in pastebin?

Comment: @markc you can see my schema http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281529/datastax-5-0-3-solr-node-does-not-reindex-just-goes-down?noredirect=1. Indeed, i tested  a lot senario playing parameters such as max_solr_concurrency, back pressure, gc settings, schema but the result is same.

Comment: It certainly looks like an indexing issue. Your schema looks ok, I can see how the field types are constructed though. I cant see your solr core config either or the tables schema. You might want to look at some of the following resources: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tuning-dse-search, also https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/performanceTuningTOC.html